# Update data in angular directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having an issue getting the data that I pass to my directive to update when the DOM updates. This directive highlights the active tab on the sidenav in relationship to where they have scrolled to on the page. Here is a [**fiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/uC2dP/12/) of what I've done.

On my local site, there are large sections that conditionally show or hide, and the user can & could be changing this often. So this then changes the position of the element ID's that I stored in `resultsSections`. When the positions change, they do not get updated in the directive.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$scope.getResultsSectionPosition = function () {
    var resultsSections = {};
    $('.results-heading').each(function () {
        resultsSections[this.parentNode.id] = $(this).offset().top;
    });
    console.log(resultsSections);
    return $scope.resultsSections = resultsSections;
}
$scope.getResultsSectionPosition();
</script>
```

I've reinitialized the local site by calling `$scope.getResultsSectionPosition()` - the new offsets are stored in `resultsSections`, but the directive still holds the initial value. **How can I force the directive to use the most active data?**

```
myApp.directive('navActive', function () {
return function(scope, element, attrs) {

        var height = $(window).height(),
            section = 0;
        $(window).bind("scroll", function() {
            var position = $(this).scrollTop();
            for (section in scope.resultsSections) {
                if (position + height - 50 >= scope.resultsSections[section]) {
                    $('li').removeClass('results-nav-active');
                    $('#nav_' + section).addClass('results-nav-active');
                };
            };
        });
    };  
})
```

I've tried useing `scope.$watch('resultsSections", function(){...})` but haven't been successful with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should ba able to use $watch, but you can also use the isolate scope attribute and then pass your controlle $scope variable directly to your directive

I tweaked a little your code and I added some console.log in order to see what happens, you can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/uC2dP/14/

I added a button on top, to force the modification of the positions, in order to see the repercussion in the directive, and in the directive I added a console.log() with the positions called on scroll. Also your directive now have an isolated scope, with the resultsSections binded to the parameter given in the HTML

```
return {
    scope:{resultsSections:"=sections"},
    link:function(scope, element, attrs) {


    var height = $(window).height(),
        section = 0;
    $(window).bind("scroll", function() {
        var position = $(this).scrollTop();
        console.log(scope.resultsSections)
        for (section in scope.resultsSections) {
            if (position + height - 50 >= scope.resultsSections[section]) {
                $('li').removeClass('results-nav-active');
                $('#nav_' + section).addClass('results-nav-active');
            };
        };
    });
}
}
```

and in the HTML :

```
<section nav-active sections="resultsSections">
```

You can see, if you click on the button then scroll, the positions in the directive are correctly updated

Have fun

Comment: And I've tried doing something similar (and just tried again) but I get an error `Error: Error while interpolating:...`. But if I comment out the `scope: [resultsSections: '=sections'}` then it goes away./

Comment: That's weird, it works well in the fiddle, and I used something similar recently. The error disappears when you comment it, that must be normal, but the value won't be updating. However, I had this error, or something similar, when I tried to pass a function in the attribute, did you try with a variable or a function ?

Comment: I'm passing in the variable `resultsSections` which actually exists in `$rootScope`

Comment: Only difference I see is that I have another directive on the same element. But the same element should be able to support multiple directives without a problem.

Comment: sorry I couldn't answer earlier, I made another fiddle using $watch, and it seems to work aswell http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/uC2dP/18/. I just modified the scope `scope:false,` and `scope.$watch("resultsSections", function(newVal, oldVal){
           scope.resultsSections=newVal;                           
            }, true);` (the true is for deep inspection)`

Comment: I got pulled to a different project. Sorry. Both of these solutions you provided do not work locally. I don't understand why. I know they are both valid. I ended up solving this by assigning things to `$rootScope` and in the directive calling `scope.$root.resultsSections`. It's a bit of a hack but it's functioning, ha. Thanks for the help.